# R go through duplicates & choose

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a data frame like this:

```
id date               amt
1  2012-05-03 10:33   32
2  2012-06-01 12:49   242
2  2012-06-05 00:09   43
3  2012-06-03 05:19   323
3  2012-06-08 08:45   12
4  2012-06-09 12:38   32
5  2012-06-09 10:31   53
```

Now I want to remove the duplicate `id`'s so that the one with the earliest date is selected. The number of duplicate entries varies. I care only about the first occurrence of each particular `id` and the corresponding `amt`, all other entries should be removed.

I understand how I can do this with a loop but I feel there can be a short and elegant solution in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like `newdata <- data[!duplicated(data$id), ]`.

EDIT: As @Aaron and others have noted below, this assumes your data is sorted:

```
testdata <- data[with(data, order(id, date)), ]

newdata <- testdata[!duplicated(testdata$id), ]
```

Comment: Yes, if the dates are sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` for elegant syntax

```
library(data.table)

 datetime <- seq(as.POSIXct("2001-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2001-01-30"), l=7)    

DT <- data.table(id = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5),x = datetime, amnt = sample(7))
DT
##    id                   x amnt
## 1:  1 2001-01-01 00:00:00    3
## 2:  2 2001-01-05 20:00:00    4
## 3:  2 2001-01-10 16:00:00    1
## 4:  3 2001-01-15 12:00:00    5
## 5:  3 2001-01-20 08:00:00    7
## 6:  4 2001-01-25 04:00:00    6
## 7:  5 2001-01-30 00:00:00    2

DT[, .SD[which.min(x)],by=id]
##    id                   x amnt
## 1:  1 2001-01-01 00:00:00    3
## 2:  2 2001-01-05 20:00:00    4
## 3:  3 2001-01-15 12:00:00    5
## 4:  4 2001-01-25 04:00:00    6
## 5:  5 2001-01-30 00:00:00    2
```

note that `data.table` will prefer keys to be `IDate.time` class not `POSIXct`, but as this solution is for coding elegance it should suffice.